# LU Factorisation (4x4 matrix) - most efficient method

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand how to do LU factorisation but I'm not sure I'm being very efficient. I first find the row echelon form of A, noting the elementary operations $E_i$ in order.

$$
E_1E_2...E_nA = U $$ then $$ L = E_1^{-1}E_2^{-1}...E_n^{-1}
$$

But is this the quickest way for a 4x4 matrix?

I've been given a class problem which (going by every other question) shouldn't take as long as it's taken me. I'd be interested to hear what method you'd be using!

$$
A =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -2 & -2 & -3 \\
  3 & -9 & 0 & -9 \\
  -1 & 2 & 4 & 7  \\
  -3 & -6 & 26 & 2
 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use Doolittle's Method:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 &0\\ l_{21} & 1 & 0 &0 \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & 1 &0 \\ l_{41} & l_{42} & l_{43} & 1 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} &u_{14}\\ 0 & u_{22} & u_{23} &u_{24} \\ 0 & 0 & u_{33} &u_{34} \\0 & 0 & 0 & u_{44} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & -2 & -3 \\  3 & -9 & 0 & -9 \\  -1 & 2 & 4 & 7  \\ -3 & -6 & 26 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Solving for each of the variables, in the correct order yields:

- $u_{11} = 1, u_{12} = -2, u_{13} = -2, u_{14} = -3$
- $l_{21} = 3, u_{22} = -3, ...$
- $l_{31} = -1, l_{32} = 4, ...$
- $\ldots $

So, we arrive at:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & -2 & -3 \\  3 & -9 & 0 & -9 \\  -1 & 2 & 4 & 7  \\ -3 & -6 & 26 & 2 \end{bmatrix} = LU = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -3 & 4 & -2 & 1\end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 & -2 & -3 \\ 0 & -3 & 6 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

We could have also used Crout's or Choleski's Method for the $LU$ approach. See: [what are pivot numbers in LU decomposition? please explain me in an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485513/what-are-pivot-numbers-in-lu-decomposition-please-explain-me-in-an-example)

Please note that sometimes an LU decomposition is not possible, and sometimes, when it is, we have to resort to using permutation matrices and other approaches.

Comment: Thank you very much! Doolittle's method certainly proved much quicker. It's certainly not a well taught concept, but your post here and on the link really helped. Much appreciated.

Comment: Gil Strang explains it very well in the first few lectures of his 18.06 linear algebra course (videos available for free on the MIT open courseware site).