# How do you find L of LU for this LU factorization?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & -7 & -2 \\
        -3 & 5 & 1 \\
        6 & -4 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
The method my book gave me of doing this is:
divide col1 by first pivot position, then I am completely lost, as my $U$ doesn't help for whatever reason I have:
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & -7 & -2 \\
        0 & -2 & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

How do I turn $-2$ & $3$ into 
$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        2 & -5 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

We can use Doolittle's Method:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ l_{21} & 1 & 0  \\ l_{31} & l_{32} & 1    \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} \\ 0 & u_{22} & u_{23} \\ 0 & 0 & u_{33}   \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        3 & -7 & -2 \\
        -3 & 5 & 1 \\
        6 & -4 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Solving for each of the variables, in the correct order yields:

- $u_{11} = 3, u_{12} = 7, u_{13} = -2$
- $l_{21} = -1, u_{22} = -2, ...$
- $l_{31} = 2, l_{32} =-5, ...$
- $\ldots $

So, we arrive at:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}3 & -7 & -2 \\-3 & 5 & 1 \\6 & -4 & 0 \\\end{bmatrix}  = LU = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 1 & 0  \\ 2& -5 & 1  \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 7 & -2  \\ 0 & -2 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & -1  \end{bmatrix}$$

We could have also used Crout's or Choleski's Method for the $LU$ approach. See: [what are pivot numbers in LU decomposition? please explain me in an example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485513/what-are-pivot-numbers-in-lu-decomposition-please-explain-me-in-an-example)

Please note that sometimes an LU decomposition is not possible, and sometimes, when it is, we have to resort to using permutation matrices and other approaches.