# Matrix factorization LU

Tags: matrices

[image]

In this example, for the third and the fourth element of the second column of matrix L, aren't them should be $m_{32}$ and $m_{42}$. And according to the definition,$m_{32}=a_{32}/a_{22}$, which in this case, should be $-1/1=-1$. Where does the 4 come from?

Comment: The result is correct.

Comment: Where did you get the 4?

Comment: $l_{31}u_{12} + l_{32}u_{22} = -1 \rightarrow 3\times 1 + l_{32}\times - 1 = -1 \implies l_{32} = 4$.

Comment: but the formula in the book is $l_{32}=m_{32}=a_{32}/a_{22}$

Comment: In general, it's $l_{ji}=m_{ji}=a_{ji}/a_{ii}$

Comment: Depends which $LU$ you are doing. The result shows they are using this one http://nucinkis-lab.cc.ic.ac.uk/HELM/workbooks/workbook_30/30_3_lu_decomposition.pdf

Comment: Are there different kinds of LU?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485513/what-are-pivot-numbers-in-lu-decomposition-please-explain-me-in-an-example