# Why WolframAlpha does LU decomposition with pivoting even when it isn't needed?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, wolfram-alpha, lu-decomposition

I want to do LU decomposition with $A$:

$
   A=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
   -9 & 8 & -15 & 4 \\
   2 & 13 & -21 & 7 \\
   4 & -5 & 5 & 3
  \end{array} } \right]
$

My answer is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,0,0,0%7D,%7B-9,1,0,0%7D,%7B2,0.346,1,0%7D,%7B4,-0.5,0.032,1%7D%7D*%7B%7B1,2,3,4%7D,%7B0,26,12,40%7D,%7B0,0,-31.154,-14.846%7D,%7B0,0,0,7.477%7D%7D), which the result is approximation because of limitations of floating point data. $A$ can be done LU decomposition without pivoting.

But [WolframAlpha](https://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LU%20decomposition%20of%20%7B%7B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%7D%2C%7B-9%2C8%2C-15%2C4%7D%2C%7B2%2C13%2C-21%2C7%7D%2C%7B4%2C-5%2C5%2C3%7D%7D) gives me different solution. They do LU decomposition with pivoting. I don't know why WolframAlpha calculate LU decomposition with pivoting even pivoting isn't needed.

Comment: Try this calculator: http://www.gregthatcher.com/Mathematics/LU_Factorization.aspx

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -9 & 1 & 0 \\
 2 & \frac{9}{26} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 0 & 26 & 12 & 40 \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{405}{13} & -\frac{193}{13} \\
 4 & -5 & 5 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 -9 & 8 & -15 & 4 \\
 2 & 13 & -21 & 7 \\
 4 & -5 & 5 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Oh this calculates LU rather than PLU. And.. no reason why WolframAlpha using pivot without any ground?

Comment: It is just the way they coded up their routine - even the professional Mathematica does it that way. I coded my own variant and produced the results above - as well as the site I provided. This is not bad to calculate by hand for such a small matrix.

Comment: Seems unclear. You mean the result(LU or PLU) depends on what algorithms are used?

Comment: Yes, it looks like Mathematica's coded algorithm always uses PLU when it can. The one I wrote does not and neither does the web site I pointed you to. See this posting for examples and links: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485513/what-are-pivot-numbers-in-lu-decomposition-please-explain-me-in-an-example

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you for the help. I wish I could accept your comments.